# How to plot graph of functions of two variables in a function in R

Tags: r

I made this derivative script and I wanted to plot the graph of the result of the derivative along with the function.
But I am not able to make the graph in the multivariate case f(x,y), the result of the derivative is taken as a value and not as a function.
See the example below:

```
DD7<-function(x,r,contador=1){

dy<- substitute(x)
if(contador<1) {

stop("Grau de derivada menor que 1")
}
if(contador==1) {

der<-D(dy,c(r))

print(der)
x<- y <- seq(-3,3,length=50)
z<- outer(x,y,der)
persp(x,y,z)
}
else {
der2<- DD(D(dy,r),r,contador-1)
print(der2)
x2<- y2 <- seq(-3,3,length=50)
z2<- outer(x,y,der2)
persp(x,y,z2)

}
}

DD7(x*y^2,"y",1)

Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
object 'der' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Comment: Typo? You define `DD7` and call `DD8`. Not reproducible: we don't have your `x` or `y` values.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the typo.
x and y are variables of the function.
The function (DD7) finds the derivative of the typed function.
In this example the derivative of (x*(y^2)) with respect to y will answer: (2*x*y).
I would like to plot the graph of the derivative (2*x*y).

Comment: (I see, sorry for the false-alarm, I understand that now.)

Comment: The third argument for `base::outer` needs to be a function, whereas `der` is a *call*. I don't know why you need `outer` there, if you call `eval(der)` in place of that, you get a vector the length of `x` and `y` (which, in this example, is the value from `y^2`, the derivative I think you're targeting). What makes you believe you need to `outer` the `x`/`y` vectors? That'll produce a vector `length(x)*length(y)` long, fyi.

Comment: eval (der) generates a vector, I don't want a vector, I need to turn (der) into a function for me to graph the function.

Comment: But you *do* need a vector, since `persp` needs the first three arguments to be equal-length vectors of numbers. However, I think I got your point: you need it to be a much-larger vector. See my answer, I think it addresses what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comments, `outer`'s third argument needs to be a function. If you use `eval(der)`, you may *infer* (correctly) that it is evaluating the expression (`y^2` in this example) based on the objects found in the calling environment (the function's environment, to be specific). Since `x` and `y` are both found, then `eval(der)` uses those variables, and returns a vector of the appropriate length.

The purpose of `outer` is to do an outer-join of the values, expanding into `length(x)*length(y)` combinations. If you look at the function as it is called by `outer`, its first argument is `length(x)*length(y)` elements long, all from the original `x`; the second argument is also that length, from the original `y`. The order of the values are such that all values from `x` are paired with all values of `y`.

Given this what we need to do is have `eval(der)` operate in *that* environment.

```r
DD7 <- function(x, r, contador=1) {
  # ...
  z2 <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) eval(der))
  persp(x, y, z2)
  # ...
}

DD7(x*y^2, "y", 1)
# x * (2 * y)
```

[image: persp plot]

In that example, it might be confusing *which* `x` and `y` are referenced when; it's straight-forward: inside the anon-function passed to `outer`, we also name them the same names so that the `eval`uated `der` will find the relevant expanded values.